# The membership provider name specified is invalid. Parameter name: providerName

Tags: c#, nhibernate, .net-4.0, nunit, asp.net-membership

- .Net4.0
- MVC 2
- NHibernate
- NUnit

I'm trying to test user creation.  From my test, I'm calling the following:

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;
// _session is my current NHibernate session.
var mmp = new MyMembershipProvider(_session);
mmp.CreateUser(username, password, "something@example.com", "", "", true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status);
```

In the `CreateUser` method, it gets this far:

```
var user = new MembershipUser(Name, username, providerUserKey, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, false, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
```

... before throwing this exception:

```
The membership provider name specified is invalid.
Parameter name: providerName
```

I have my Name set to `MyMembershipProvider`, and in the Web.config I have this:

```
<add name="OnyxMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
  enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
  applicationName="/" />
```

And also, my connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now, I'm guessing the the problem is that my tests are creating a SQLite DB, and the web.Config is trying to hit my SqlServer DB, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you show the web.config line relating to the connection string named "ApplicationServices" ? (remove any passwords of course :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shouldn't the name be the same as that specified in the web.config?

i.e. OnyxMembershipProvider

Comment: I think this fixed it, and I never marked it as the answer.  Sorry for taking so long!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider mocking the membership provider.  Your unit tests should be testing *your* code, not Microsoft's.

Here's some information on using Moq to mock out the membership provider:

[What am I doing wrong this time with Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054871/what-am-i-doing-wrong-this-time-with-moq)

Comment: Slight problem... I'm using WatiN, so I don't have access to the controller directly.  I don't think I can mock like that, can I?